# Are there any CreateEvent, WaitForSingleObject and SetEvent equivalents in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, port

Recently I need to port my project from Windows to Linux, but some WIN32 API exists, like CreateEvent, WaitForSingleObject, SetEvent etc. Are there any equivalents for those in Linux? Linux OS API or function implemented by yourself are both ok.

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't mentioned programming language you use. For example in C++11 you can do this. The example you can find here: https://github.com/moya-lang/Event